# Give __init__ parameter to inner class a call it from global

Tags: python

I have this inner and outer class.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    class Cat:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
        def meow():
            print(self.name)
```

And now I need to do something like this:

```
sophia = Animal.Cat("Sophia")
sophia.meow() # output: "Sophia" #
```

How can I do this?

I know another way how can I do it, but without inner class and I don't want do to it without inner class.

So I need my "enrollment" of classes.

Comment: It is better to use inheritance... Rather than what you are doing in your code...

Comment: Apart from the `self` parameter missing in `meow`, your code woks as intended.

Comment: How is the outer class relevant to the problem at all?

Answer (score 0):

`meow()` is a function inside class, so you need:

```
def meow(self):
```

Also note there's no reason to use a nested class. And by the naming conventions you used `Animal` - `Cat` can be a super - sub class model (inheritance).